# How to handle contact by recruiters for companies you may want to interview with in the very near future

Tags: job-search

For my own sanity I'm trying to limit the number of companies I'm currently interviewing with to 3. If I get an offer or a rejection from one, and if time allows, I'll apply to yet another I'm interested in.

If I'm already interviewing with three companies, and I get contacted by recruiter B from another company I'm interested in, what's the best way to handle that?

I hesitate to be frank about what I'm doing because it seems like that would suggest to recruiter B that they're a second choice. But do they actually care? What is the best way to respond?

Comment: Hi and welcome to The Worplace. Now, I'm a bit confused, is recruiter B from one of those 3 companies ? (Why 'B'?). And why limiting yourself to 3 specifically. As a general rule, recruiters usually expect you to be looking at others companies, and don't take it badly. But could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with saying "not right now, but let me take your info and I may get back to you in a few weeks.". You've already made the decision that you're willing to risk someone else getting to that interview first.

Answer (score 0):

If you really consider this company as a potential choice, don't let it slope to another candidate.

They're coming to you, don't let that chance* go away. ( * : this depends on how they found you. For them are you part of a big pool or did they already eliminate some profiles?).

Maybe you could consider limiting you to 3 companies you're interviewing from your own initiative, but allow one or two more interview process from companies which contacted you.

They are seeking right now. In a few weeks it may be too late.

Imagine, that you put it away for later. They may found someone in the mean time. If the three companies you are currently interviewing end up in no-go, what is left for you ?
From your point of view, less interesting companies.